# Wordpress and nginx all pages works fine except for non-existent .php

Tags: linux, nginx, wordpress

I configured my WordPress website on Nginx and everything works fine but for non-existent .php pages Those return the nginx default 404 page not found why?

```
# listen 443 ssl default_server;
# listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
#
# Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
# See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
#
# Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
# See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
#
# Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
# Don't use them in a production server!
#
# include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

root /var/www/vpsproject.site;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.php;

server_name vpsproject.site;


location / {
    #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;



}


# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    # With php7.4-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}

      # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
    # deny access to .git related folders or files
    #
    location ~ /\.git {
            deny all;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because nginx sends the requests for `.php` files to the PHP-FPM process listening at `unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock` socket. PHP-FPM process then checks if the file exists, and if it does't exist, it returns 404 status code.

Meanwhile, the default request flow for all other URLs is that nginx first checks if file or directory exists. If it exists, it sends the content.

Otherwise nginx sends the request to `/index.php`, which then gets sent to the PHP-FPM process via the socket.

Then WordPress front controller handles the request, and serves its own 404 page if it is not found.